# shinymeta works locally but breaks when published to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am exploring the exciting new shinymeta package for generating reproducible code from shiny apps. Following the examples [here](https://rstudio.github.io/shinymeta/articles/code-generation.html), I have made an app that works on my local machine but fails when I publish to shinyapps.io

Below is a minimal example which reproduces the error, i.e. works fine locally, but fails when published to shinyapps.io.

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymeta)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyAce)

ui <- fluidPage(
    outputCodeButton(plotOutput("p1"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$p1 <- metaRender(renderPlot, {
        hist(diamonds$carat)
    })


observeEvent(input$p1_output_code, {
    code <- expandChain(output$p1())
    displayCodeModal(code)
})    

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In my local environment, this code works as expected. The app presents a histogram of `diamonds$carat` with a "Show Code" button above. Clicking the "Show Code" button opens a box with the line of code needed to generate the graph (i.e. `hist(diamonds$carat)`) which is passed via the `expandChain()` function.

When I publish the app to shinyapps.io, the app renders ok. However, when I click the "Show Code" button the code does not appear and the app disconnects from the server.

I am running R 3.6.1 on macOS. I have the free shinyapps.io account (but my other practice shiny apps have published without issue).

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examining the logs on shinapps.io, the problem appeared to be with the `clipr` package. This is a dependency of `shinymeta` but for some reason didn't seem to be called automatically the way other dependencies are. Adding the following code to the app.R file fixed the problem:

```
library(clipr)
```